# What can change my floating point control word behind my back?

Tags: python, c, windows, delphi, floating-point

I have a 32 bit Windows application, written primarily in Delphi, which performs floating point numerical simulations using the 8087 FPU. I have recently added the ability to link in external Python code using the Python API through python2x.dll. This recent change has led to some very strange behaviour.

The application has a batch mode of operation where it performs multiple simulations in parallel to take advantage of multi-core architectures. As soon as Python code has been executed in the process, I start to see changes to the 8087 control word on different threads. I've checked this very carefully and I have observed the control word having changed even in a thread which has never called into the Python DLL.

I know this sounds fantastical, but, as I have discovered, there are mechanisms for this behaviour to manifest. I have learnt about signals. I first hypothesised that the Python DLL was setting process wide signal handlers (by calling [`signal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) and these signal handlers were responsible for changing the control word. For example, a thread, unrelated to the Python code, could perhaps cause `SIGFPE` and that may, in turn, modify the control word.

I have rather come to the conclusion that `signal()` is not the mechanism. I arranged to execute the Python code at startup. Then I set of the signal handlers back to `SIG_DFL`. Then I started the simulations. But still the control word changes occurred.

My question (finally) is whether anyone knows of another mechanism by which the control word could be changed in such a manner. I'm looking for interrupts, APCs etc., I think!

**Update**

The control word is being changed to `0x037F` which is the Intel default value. This differs from the MSVC/Windows default of `0x027F`. I hypothesise that something is calling `FPINIT`.

I also discovered [`Py_InitializeEx`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#Py_InitializeEx) which allows the caller to stop Python setting signal handlers. The control word changes occur even if I use this approach to initialisation so I'm even more convinced that is not the mechanism.

Comment: I wonder if there're any callbacks or Asynchronous Procedure Calls (APCs) or something like that happening and changing the state. Just a hypothesis, never seen it actually happen.

Comment: Interrupts must not adversely affect the FPU state. That would break everything. And I do not expect Python to do anything in the kernel space to mess interrupt handling as it's just a piece of user-mode code, not a kernel-mode driver.

Comment: if you are using any graphical output API for the simulations, they can also fiddle with the FPU control (DirectX is notorious for this)

Comment: @Necrolis These calculation threads don't touch DirectX. Other threads in the process do (and of course have to restore the control word after calling out).

Comment: Are you calling any .NET assembly ?

Comment: @LU RD No .net anywhere. I have for many years successfully run these threads without any changes to control word. It is just the presence of Python in the process that has triggered the new behaviour.

Comment: I know too little about Python, but can a flawed exception handling cause this behavior ? A sidenote, [this](http://www.dewresearch.com/borland-delphi.html) math library make good use of the math processor in multicore environments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Btw, could Python corrupt your app in an interesting way so that it does it to itself?

Comment: @Alex I think this would cause Python any problem because the control word is changed to the Intel/Windows default which is what Python expects. It's a bind for me because I'm using Delphi which expects a different control word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Third party code is modifying the FPU control word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933690/third-party-code-is-modifying-the-fpu-control-word)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: See if this leads anywhere: http://www.opening-windows.com/techart_windows_vista_apc_internals.htm

Comment: I guess you've already considered this, but the best way of avoiding the problem might be to run all the Python stuff in a subprocess.

Comment: @Harry Yeah that thought had occurred thanks. I'd need full two-way IPC which is just too much to contemplate right now. Sadly the interface is not COM which would of course make it easier to hive off in a separate process.

Comment: Do you know whether the issue affects threads that were started before the Python library was loaded?

Comment: @Harry Yes, such threads are affected.

Comment: Assuming the problem continues to happen even after you've stopped explicitly executing Python code, perhaps you could make all the code in the Python DLL non-executable so that an exception will occur as soon as any of the code runs?  With any luck the call stack from the exception will give you more information about under what circumstances Python is hijacking your threads and maybe a hint about why.

Comment: @Harry That sounds like a very good idea. I'll give that a bash.

Comment: @DavidHefferman:  Which version of Python?  I'd be interested to know whether you see issues with Python 2.7 but not with Python 2.6.  Python 2.7 will explicitly mess with the FPU control word in some cases.

Comment: To add an example to my previous comment:  see http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/pymath.c

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Behaviour same in 2.6 and 2.7. I don't mind what Python does to control word when I call it since when it returns I restore it to my control word. Problem is that something in the system is changing the control word in threads that are not executing Python code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Hmm, that's a puzzle.  Sorry for the useless comments (and for misspelling your name in the previous comment.)

Answer (score 5):

For example, a `DllMain` call with `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` flag, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Update**

I have found a link to similar problem - [DLL Load "Poisons" FPU Control Word for New Threads](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/591245/dll-load-poisons-fpu-control-word-for-new-threads#). But yes, it is about the threads created *after* Dll load.

Comment: That doesn't quite explain it because the control word changes long after the thread has been created. `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` would explain a control word change at the very beginning of the thread's life. Have I understood your point correctly?

Comment: `DllMain` is also called when you call `LoadLibrary`. Not sure that the calls are done per thread though - never had such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, that's Delphi's problem. There are some discussions of the issue [here](http://www.paranoia.clara.net/articles/delphi4_lizard_taming.html) and [here](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/delphi-michael-justin-had-strange-floating-point-results-when-his-8087-fpu-control-word-got-hosed/). I remember bumping into it when trying to write some VST plugins in Delphi.

Comment: It's not Delphi's problem. I fully understand that when calling into external code that expects the Intel/Windows default control word, I need to set that (and restore it on return) for code that omits to do so. The problem is that code in my thread has the control word changed behind its back.

Comment: There is SafeLoadLibrary in the RTL which does exactly this. Not using it is the problem ;)

Comment: @mjn The control word is being changed independent of any LoadLibrary calls. When dealing with control word incompatibilities between modules it is insufficient to use just LoadLibrary. You have to patrol every crossing of a module boundary. Every single call into another module is a potential pitfall. So using SafeLoadLibrary doesn't get you very far.

Comment: @David now I do understand - every DLL call can do bad things to the CW. Too bad we can not refactor away all global variables in the CPU :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a case like this where the printer driver of the default printer changed the control word in my back. When I changed the default printer, the problem went away.
To circumvent this problem I set the control word to the default value at approriate places with:

`_control87(_CW_DEFAULT, _CW_DEFAULT);`

I have also seen the same problem on all machines of a customer that had Norton Security 2011 installed, but the problem went away with the fix for the printer driver, so I'm not really sure if Norton was really the cause.