# Why does dllMain overrides the control-word of my FPU?

Tags: python, c, windows, fpu, dllmain

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687673/what-can-change-my-floating-point-control-word-behind-my-back?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/591245/dll-load-poisons-fpu-control-word-for-new-threads#) that `dllMain` changes the control-word of my FPU, and I need to:

```
_control87(_CW_DEFAULT, _CW_DEFAULT);
```

so it will return to normal. But no one states why it is done.

Does anyone know why does my dllMain do that? On what compiler? Only visual studio? And why did Microsoft decided this was a good idea to set my FPU control-word without me knowing for every one of my dlls? Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: I've not seen visual studio do this but I've heard that Delphi does (or did) - are you saying it inserts boilerplate code or what?

Comment: None of the answers on the two articles you reference blame Microsoft DLLs for this problem.  There's mention of Python, Delphi, Lahey Fortran 90, and an unspecified printer driver, but no mention of any Microsoft products.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Okay, but I do see this happen in my DLL compiled by visual studio 2008. How do you explain this?

Comment: Well, what code is in your DllMain function?  What DLL dependencies does your DLL have?