# Testing for a float NaN results in a stack overflow

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, nan

C#, VS 2010

I need to determine if a float value is NaN.

Testing a float for NaN using

```
float.IsNaN(aFloatNumber)
```

crashes with a stack overflow.

So does

```
aFloatNumber.CompareTo(float.NaN).
```

The following does not crash, but it's not useful as it returns NaN regardless:

```
aFloatNumber - float.NaN
```

A search for "stack overflow" returns results about this website instead of results about an actual stack overflow, so I can't find relevant answers.

Why is my application going into a stack overflow when testing for NaN?

Edit: the call stack:

[image]

Edit: it's clearly something in my code: this statement:

```
bool aaa = float.IsNaN(float.NaN);
```

- works OK in the constructor of the application, right after InitializeComponent();
- works OK in the constructor of theclass for a custom control, right after InitializeComponent();
- but crashes in an event handler inside the class for a custom control.

So, this is what I am doing:

- Abstract Custom control: public abstract partial class ConfigNumberBaseBox : TextBox
- has a Validating event handler ValidateTextBoxEntry
- ValidateTextBoxEntry is defined inside the ConfigNumberBaseBox class
- Custom control that inherits from ConfigNumberBaseBox : public partial class ConfigTemperBox : ConfigNumberBaseBox
- Run the app
- When I finish editing a ConfigTemperBox control, ValidateTextBoxEntry  is called
- ValidateTextBoxEntry  runs fine until it encounters float.IsNaN
- stack overflow

Edit:

Debug.WriteLine() shows that the code is executed only once: no recursion.

Edit:

This works:

```
float fff = 0F;
int iii = fff.CompareTo(float.PositiveInfinity);
```

This crashes:

```
float fff = 0F;
int iii = fff.CompareTo(float.NaN);
```

Comment: I don't believe it's the comparison, it must be something else in your code. what is the callstack when you get the stackoverflow?

Comment: `IsNaN` is defined as `return (*(int*)(&f) & 0x7FFFFFFF) > 0x7F800000;`. This just can't do a stack overflow by itself. There's something wrong in your code.

Comment: Create a minimal example that shows this behavior.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the call stack. Not much there.

Comment: It will take me some time to create a minimal example. As soon as I do I will post it here.

Comment: Does your application depend on other modules?  I know one case can case this kind crash: when the default floating control word has been changed

Comment: Can you post the other code in the event handler?

Comment: it's probably the debugger showing you the exception on an unrelated line, look elsewhere if you have a recursion

Comment: @thumbmunkeys > look elsewhere if you have a recursion --- no recursion, (at least not intentionally)

Comment: `ValidateTextBoxEntry` is probably called recursively (unintentionally of course :), make a `Debug.WriteLine()` in there and watch the output of your app

Comment: @Matt > Does your application depend on other modules? --- No

Comment: Possibly called recursively _through inheritance_.

Comment: You need to show the code involved, ie. the code containing that call.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys >   ValidateTextBoxEntry is probably called recursively --- I am stepping through the code with the F11 key. If there were recursion, I would see it re-enter the code.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I might be wrong then. But I'd still try a Debug statement, as a lot of other framework internal code might be running between the recursions, so you might have missed it.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys > make a Debug.WriteLine() in there and watch the output of your app --- Done. It shows that the code is executed only once. No recursion.

Comment: Since you don't seem able to create a minimal example, look for something bizarre like an extension method on float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution**:

First of all, thank you to @Matt for pointing me in the right direction, and @Hans Passant for providing the workaround.

The application talks to a CAN-USB adapter from Chinese manufacturer QM_CAN.

The problem is in their driver.

The DLL statements and Driver import:

```
   // DLL Statement
    IntPtr QM_DLL;
    TYPE_Init_can Init_can;
    TYPE_Quit_can Quit_can;
    TYPE_Can_send Can_send;
    TYPE_Can_receive Can_receive;
    delegate int TYPE_Init_can(byte com_NUM, byte Model, int CanBaudRate, byte SET_ID_TYPE, byte FILTER_MODE, byte[] RXF, byte[] RXM);
    delegate int TYPE_Quit_can();
    delegate int TYPE_Can_send(byte[] IDbuff, byte[] Databuff, byte FreamType, byte Bytes);
    delegate int TYPE_Can_receive(byte[] IDbuff, byte[] Databuff, byte[] FreamType, byte[] Bytes);

    // Driver
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);
```

The call to the offending code, including Hans' workaround:

```
   private void InitCanUsbDLL() // Initiate the driver for the CAN-USB dongle
    {

        // Here is an example of dynamically loaded DLL functions
        QM_DLL = LoadLibrary("QM_USB.dll");
        if (QM_DLL != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr P_Init_can = GetProcAddress(QM_DLL, "Init_can");
            IntPtr P_Quit_can = GetProcAddress(QM_DLL, "Quit_can");
            IntPtr P_Can_send = GetProcAddress(QM_DLL, "Can_send");
            IntPtr P_Can_receive = GetProcAddress(QM_DLL, "Can_receive");
            // The next line results in a FPU stack overflow if float.NaN is called by a handler
            Init_can = (TYPE_Init_can)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(P_Init_can, typeof(TYPE_Init_can));
            // Reset the FPU, otherwise we get a stack overflow when we work with float.NaN within a event handler
            // Thanks to Matt for pointing me in the right direction and to Hans Passant for this workaround:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205112/testing-for-a-float-nan-results-in-a-stack-overflow/25206025
            try { throw new Exception("Please ignore, resetting FPU"); }
            catch { } 
            Quit_can = (TYPE_Quit_can)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(P_Quit_can, typeof(TYPE_Quit_can));
            Can_send = (TYPE_Can_send)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(P_Can_send, typeof(TYPE_Can_send));
            Can_receive = (TYPE_Can_receive)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(P_Can_receive, typeof(TYPE_Can_receive));
        }
    }
```

The reason that the application crashed when a reference was made to float.NaN in the event handler and not in the constructor was a simple matter of timing: the constructor is called before InitCanUsbDLL(), but the event handler was called long after InitCanUsbDLL() corrupted the FPU registers.

Comment: I was really surprised by it. My advice: create seperate process using this driver and communicate with your main by some inter-process-communication technique (e.g. TCP or some message-queues). I had strange problems with some other native library and this solves it (as well as 32bit-only library on 64bit system problem). Best would be to create your middle-process in C++.

Comment: Assuming this doesn't change behavior, I would put `try { throw new Exception("Please ignore, resetting FPU"); } catch { } ` in its own one-line function.  Having a function which *only* contains a try...catch helps make it clear which code is part of the FPU fix and which is not.

Answer (score 30):

> works OK in the constructor of theclass for a custom control

This is the only real hint towards the underlying problem.  Code that runs on a thread can manipulate *two* stacks inside the processor.  One is the normal one that everybody knows about and gave this web site its name.  There is however another one, well hidden inside the FPU (Floating Point Unit).  It stores intermediate operand values while making floating point calculations.  It is 8 levels deep.

Any kind of mishap inside the FPU is *not* supposed to generate runtime exceptions.  The CLR assumes that the FPU is configured with its defaults for the FPU control word, the hardware exceptions it can generate are supposed to be disabled.

That does have a knack for going wrong when your program uses code that came from the 1990s, back when enabling FPU exceptions still sounded like a good idea.  Code generated by Borland tooling are notorious for doing this for example.  Its C runtime module *reprograms* the FPU control word and unmasks the hardware exceptions.  The kind of exceptions you can get for that can be *very* mysterious, using NaN in your code is a good way to trigger such an exception.

This should be at least partially visible with the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on the "still good" code and use the Debug + Windows + Registers debugger window.  Right-click it and select "Floating point".  You'll see all of the registers that are involved with floating point calculations, ST0 through ST7 are the stack registers for example.  The important one here is marked `CTRL`, its normal value in a .NET process is `027F`.  The last 6 bits in that value are the exception masking bits (0x3F), all turned on to prevent hardware exceptions.

Single step through the code and the expectation is that you see the CTRL value change.  As soon as it does then you'll have found the evil code.  If you enable unmanaged debugging then you should also see the load notification in the Output window and see it appear in the Debug + Windows + Module window.

Undoing the damage that the DLL did is fairly awkward.  You'd have to pinvoke _control87() in msvcrt.dll for example to restore the CTRL word.  Or a simple trick that you can use, you can *intentionally* throw an exception.  The exception handling logic inside the CLR resets the FPU control word.  So with some luck, this kind of code is going to solve your problem:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    try { throw new Exception("Please ignore, resetting FPU"); }
    catch {}
```

You may have to move it, next best guess is the Load event.  The debugger should tell you where.

Comment: By Golly! If I add you code just before the reference to float.NaN, I no longer get the Stack Overflow. (Placing it in the constructor makes no difference).

Comment: Well good, I guessed at this problem correctly.  You ought to find a better place for it, right after that DLL got loaded is the best place.  Use the debugger as I described to find that place.

Comment: jesus i hope to be at this level one day

Comment: So, do I just "wave my hands" and add that code as a hack, or do I really need to delve deep into it and find out what really is going on? That is: do you think my crappy code is to blame, or that this is something beyond crappy code writing?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with your "crappy code", it is somebody else's.  Not taking a dependency on code that you don't know about, can't really support and whose programmers probably have moved on a long time ago is of course best.  I can't give you that kind of advice of course, this is entirely up to you to decide.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Hans Passant is saying there is some external code/component you are using that [changes the control word](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6933690/11683).

Comment: Fun fact, the original 1990s era JavaScript and VBScript engines from Microsoft detect when the floating point control words change values across a call to a third-party component and restore them to their proper values. Take a guess as to how I know that particular arcane fact. :-)

Comment: For others that might be passing by: the "exception resets" thing is only there in 32bit builds of the CLR the 64bit builds don't do it (also see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/coreclr/src/vm/excep.cpp#L7857)). Also 32bit builds raise an SEHException when hardware exceptions are enabled, whereas 64bit builds raise an ArithmethicException.

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote an example to reproduce the error:
1. Create a  native C/C++ DLL which exports this function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  int SetfloatingControlWord(void)
{
    //unmask all the floating excetpions
    int err = _controlfp_s(NULL, 0, _MCW_EM);    
    return err;
}
```

2. Create a C# console program, which call the function SetfloatingControlWord, after that, do some floating operation such as NaN compare, then it leads to stack overflow.

```
 [DllImport("floatcontrol.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SetfloatingControlWord();       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int n =   SetfloatingControlWord();          
           float fff = 0F;
           int iii = fff.CompareTo(float.NaN);
        }
```

I encountered the same problem years ago, also, I noticed that after an .NET exception throws, everything works fine, it took me a while to figure out why and trace the code which changed the FPU.

As the doc of function [_controlfp_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9676k6h.aspx) says: By default, the run-time libraries mask all floating-point exceptions. The common language runtime (CLR) only supports the default floating-point precision, so CLR doesn't handle these kind exceptions.

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679349(v=vs.85).aspx) says:By default, the system has all FP exceptions turned off. Therefore, computations result in NAN or INFINITY, rather than an exception.

After NaN was introduced in IEEE 754 1985, it suppose that application software no longer need to handle the floating point exceptions.

Comment: You have advanced my search for the problem immensely. Thank you! I will post the answer and refer to you as the inspiration.